# Statically linking fontconfig: disable `fonts.conf` file

Tags: fontconfig

My application statically links `libfontconfig.a` on macOS, but does not ship with any fontconfig configuration files.

Each time the application starts, it gives a warning about `fonts.conf` not found. After that it falls back on default fontconfig settings and everything works great. Is there a way to build or configure `fontconfig` to never use `fonts.conf` and instead always use default settings?

Answer (score 1):

I think, the question's itself is actually about to find out this missing file.

Currently your application's details are unclear, such as target platform Mac OS X or iOS (*so this answer could be updated if OP provides more information*) but I think you have deleted `fonts.conf` accidentally and:

According to Synopsis of `man fonts-conf` or [online manual](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/fontconfig/fontconfig-user.html). For Linux `fonts.conf` is normally located:

```
/etc/fonts/fonts.conf
/etc/fonts/fonts.dtd
/etc/fonts/conf.d
$XDG_CONFIG_HOME/fontconfig/conf.d
$XDG_CONFIG_HOME/fontconfig/fonts.conf
~/.fonts.conf.d
~/.fonts.conf
```

But in your case this file is must be shipped with your application, because Mac OS X and iOS apps don't rely on dependencies. So I tried to find a `fonts.conf` file on my MacBook with:

```
sudo /usr/libexec/locate.updatedb
locate fonts.conf
```

Incidentally I have found it under [GIMP](https://www.gimp.org/downloads/):

```
/Applications/GIMP.app/Contents/Resources/etc/fonts/fonts.conf
```

Later on I have decided to search it in GitHub and I found it under these repositories:
1|https://github.com/EricssonResearch/cerbero/blob/master/data/xcode/templates/ios/GStreamer%20Base.xctemplate/fontconfig/fonts.conf
2|https://github.com/xil3f/podofo_iOS_sample/blob/cd0be2d225d0bdfbe3c0ec163fb4cce67534825f/fonts/fonts.conf

These files are nearly identical.

For a cross-platform Linux-originated Mac OS X app it's located in: `./Contents/Resources/etc/fonts/fonts.conf`

For iOS sample apps it's located in: `./fontconfig/fonts.conf` or `./fonts/fonts.conf`

So these locations can give you an idea about where to put `fonts.conf` file on your project.

You can either try to put these `fonts.conf` files above to necessary location(s) or you can use this [sample configuration file](https://opensource.apple.com/source/X11fonts/X11fonts-14/fontconfig.osx-fonts.conf) provided by Apple Open Source for OS X:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE fontconfig SYSTEM "fonts.dtd">
<fontconfig>
    <dir>/System/Library/Fonts</dir>
    <dir>/Library/Fonts</dir>
    <dir>~/Library/Fonts</dir>
</fontconfig>
```

P.S. Please OP leave a comment so we can improve the answer together.